# Wireshark to decrypt SSL mutual

Tags: ssl, wireshark

Is there any way to decrypt mutual SSL (client & server, two ways) ?

I found this link : https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201001/msg00147.html

But I am still not able to decrypt. I am not sure about the client port.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to get it working by following this tuto: https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/